# ucwordsのucって何ぞや

Tags: php

`ucwords`は文字列中のそれぞれの単語の始めの1文字を大文字に変換する関数ですが、
なぜ`ucwords`というのですか？`uc`は何の略ですか？

Comment: [PHP: ucwords](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php)を見ると `ucwords - Uppercase the first character of each word in a string` と記載されているいるので `UpperCase` の略でしょう、きっと。

Answer (score 4):

「**U**pper **C**ase」の略です。